# How to show values as percentage of column total in R like in excel pivot table?

Tags: r, pivot-table

I have a data frame like below

```
col1 col2 col3
x     17    15
y     18    20
z     20    14
```

I want to shows row values as percentage of column totals tried like below

```
data$percentage_col2 <- data$col2/(sum(data$col2))
data$percentage_col3 <- data$col3/(sum(data$col3))

Output :

col1 col2 col3  percentage_col2   percentage_col3
x     17    15     0.3090           0.3061
y     18    20     0.3272           0.4081
z     20    14     0.3636           0.2857
```

Desired output :

```
col1    col2       col3     
x     0.3090%     0.3061%
y     0.3272%     0.4081%
z     0.3636%     0.2857%
```

Please,help me,How to get output like that.

Comment: Try `data %>% mutate_at(vars(col2:col3), ~ ./sum(.))` or with `data %>% mutate(across(col2:col3, ~ str_c(./sum(.), "%")))`

Comment: Or use `percent_format` i..e `data %>%mutate(across(col2:col3, ~ scales::percent_format(scale = 1)(./sum(.))))`

Comment: @ akrun, Thank you.That link you provided me answered my question.